# jQuery UI Dialog - Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this piece of code:

```
function onRegisterPostSucces(data){
    $("#registerForm").dialog("close");
    $("#registerDialog").text(data);
    $("#registerDialog").dialog( "open" );
```

What I want to do is send register data from dialog form, and on success I want to close register dialog and open new dialog with information about creating a new account.
But in line with dialog("close") I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
```

I tried following solutions:

```
$("#registerForm").dialog().dialog("close");
```

And

```
$("#registerForm").hide
```

But both didn't close the dialog - only hide that which was is dialog (for example inputs), dialog was still open. What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** Initialization:

```
$("#registerDialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
 $("#registerBar").dialog({autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400, height: 600, 
            buttons: {"Zamknij": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
            }}});
(...)
```

In #registerBar I have #registerForm:

```
$("#registerForm").submit(sendRegisterFormData);
function sendRegisterFormData(e){
    var contextPath='<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
    $.post(contextPath+"/login/AddUser", $("#registerForm").serialize(),
        onRegisterPostSucces);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

And onRegisterPostSuccess I want to close the dialog. Button which triggered POST is not "dialog-owned" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see where you instantiated your dialog, like so (as an example):

$("#registerForm").dialog("close");

```
function onRegisterPostSucces(data){
    $("#registerForm").hide();
    $("#registerBar").dialog('close');
    $("#registerDialog").text(data);
    $("#registerDialog").dialog( "open" );
```

//  this is just an an example, you probably don't need this.

```
 $("#registerForm").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     height: 300,
     width: 300,
     modal: true,
     // etc.. other things
     close: function() {
         $(this).dialog("close");
     }
   });
```

My guess is that you didn't instantiate it yet or the 'this' reference is not correct? Sorry if I am offbase, as I do not have eyes on the full breadth of your code.

Comment: I updated my post. 'Save button' is not a part of dialog, it is form submit button. That is because it wasn't dialog before. Do you suggest that I should make it "dialog-owned" button? I am not sure but I think it can cause some problem, because then it will not be form submit buton.

Comment: ok, but what I am confused about is this: $("#registerForm").dialog("close"); You are trying to use the dialog plugin with "this" as "registerForm". If you just want to add a callback in onRegisterPostSucces, I updated my answer.

Comment: Shame on me :) You are right, I tried open dialog on "...Bar" and close it on "...Form", that's why it didn't work. If I change it, It works very well - thank you for help! :)